# Python: Do string substitution with variables at function definition time

Tags: python, scope, functional-programming

I have a situation like the following:

```
functions = []
some_list = [('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')]

for x, y in some_list:
    def foo(z):
        # do some things
        return "{} {} {}".format(x, y, z)
    functions.append(foo)
```

But obviously this doesn't work, as `x` and `y` will always have the last values they had in the loop, i.e. 'c' and 'd', i.e. both functions in the `functions` list will return `'{} c d'.format(z)` in practice.

How do I make it so that it does the string substitution immediately, so that on the first loop it defines foo(z) as the equivalent to

```
def foo(z):
    # do some things
    return "{} a b".format(z)
```

without any reference to the variables `x` and `y`?

**EDIT:** I now realize I also need to store a copy of `foo` in `functions`, not `foo` itself, but the rest of the question stll stands.

Comment: Default parameter values are [famously](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941/3001761) bound at definition time.

Comment: Why do you need to have an array of functions? Wouldn't it be easier to accept the 3 parameters for `foo` and just pass them later?

Comment: @arielnmz the real example is a little bit more complicated and involves creating a class inside the loop using type(), with different variations of foo() then being added to its attributes.

Comment: @jonrsharpe this does exactly what I want, but it feels like a bit of a hack

Comment: You can use `functools.partial` to apply the function partially on each loop iteration, so you'd end up with a list of functions each bound to different `x` and `y` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could bind the loop values to local variables at function definition time:

```
for x, y in some_list:
    def foo(z, a=x, b=y):
        return "{} {} {}".format(a, b, z)
    functions.append(foo)

functions[0]('foo')
'a b foo'

functions[1]('foo')
'c d foo'
```